# Vagrant error: The host path of the shared folder is missing: ~/Code

Tags: php, laravel, vagrant

```
folders:
    - map: ~/Code
      #to: /home/vagrant/Code
      to: C:\Users\Janes-Laptop\Documents\my-webapp

sites:
    - map: homestead.app
      to: /home/vagrant/Code/public
```

I have above setting in my homestead.yml, does it make sense? I got error of `The host path of the shared folder is missing: ~/Code`

Comment: Is that the correct path to your Code directory?

Answer (score 1):

Your yaml file is currently doing this (using the vagrant ruby syntax)

```
map = '~/Code'
to = 'C:\Users\Janes-Laptop\Documents\my-webapp'
Vagrant.configure("2") do |config|
  config.vm.synced_folder map, to
end
```

relevant bit from 'basic usage' on the [vagrant site](https://www.vagrantup.com/docs/synced-folders/basic_usage.html):

> The first parameter is a path to a directory on the host machine. If
>   the path is relative, it is relative to the project root. The second
>   parameter must be an absolute path of where to share the folder within
>   the guest machine. This folder will be created (recursively, if it
>   must) if it does not exist.

All of that to say, try reversing the two. I'm guessing that you want:

```
folders:
    - map: C:\Users\Janes-Laptop\Documents\my-webapp
      to: /home/vagrant/Code
```

I hope that works, and helps explain some of why you do it that way :).

Comment: I looked at seven different worthless answers before seeing this.  nice work.